# Hibernate mapping for varchar primary key

Tags: hibernate

I have set primary key as varchar in table. But when I am trying to map this in hibernate I get error as below:

```
Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

Hibernate mapping :

```
@Id
@Column(name="LOGIN_ID",columnDefinition="VARCHAR")
private String id;
```

How can I map varchar primary key in hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

can you try using

```
@Id
@Column(name = "LOGIN_ID", nullable = false, columnDefinition="VARCHAR(64)")
```

also add a constructor to initialize the above instance variable along with a default constructor.

Comment: @Id
 @Column(name="LOGIN_ID", nullable = false,columnDefinition="VARCHAR(64)")
 private String id;public String getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(String id) {
  this.id = id;
 }. I tried as above , but still I get same error

Answer (score 0):

You can use uuid strategy, it will generate uuid as string id in your database, you don't need to set id, hibernate will take care of it.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid" )
private String id;
```